# Using GSON to parse a JSON with dynamic "key" and "value" in android

Tags: android, json, gson

I am currently working on an android project that requires me to invoke a web service that will return me a json file. I have been using GSON library to parse all the json file and get a JSON object. It has been working well until I come across this json data which the key fields are dynamic. An example of this file is as below:

```
{ "0": { "count":"5"},
  "1": { "title":"...", "desc":"" },
  "2": { "title":"...", "desc":"" },
  "3": { "title":"...", "desc":"" },
  "4": { "title":"...", "desc":"" },
  "5": { "title":"...", "desc":"" },
  "routes": { "route1":"...", "route3":"" },
}
```

I am able to get the count based on the key id of "0", but I am not sure how do I make use of this value to get the other key objects (key id 1-5), which consist of the data that I needed. Will really appreciate if anyone is able to help me in this matter. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to add that if your map is not nested than things are much simpler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The most straightforward approach I can think of is to just treat the structure as a `Map` (of `Map`).

With Gson, this is relatively easy to do, as long as the `Map` structure is statically known, every branch from the root has the same depth, and everything is a `String`.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String,Map<String, String>> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), mapType);
    System.out.println(map);

    // Get the count...
    int count = Integer.parseInt(map.get("0").get("count"));

    // Get each numbered entry...
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Entry " + i + ":");
      Map<String, String> numberedEntry = map.get(String.valueOf(i));
      for (String key : numberedEntry.keySet())
        System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", key, numberedEntry.get(key));
    }

    // Get the routes...
    Map<String, String> routes = map.get("routes");

    // Get each route...
    System.out.println("Routes:");
    for (String key : routes.keySet())
      System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", key, routes.get(key));
  }
}
```

For more dynamic `Map` structure handling, I strongly suggest switching to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), instead of Gson, as Jackson will deserialize any JSON object of any arbitrary complexity into a Java `Map`, with just one simple line of code, and it will automatically retain the types of primitive values.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map map = mapper.readValue(new File("input.json"), Map.class);
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

The same can be achieved with Gson, but it requires dozens of lines of code.  (Plus, Gson has other shortcomings that make switching to Jackson well worth it.)

Comment: In Gson currently this works: Map jsondata =  g.fromJson(injson, Map.class);

Answer (score -1):

You can just get the individual key objects using the count. So you would get object "1" and then get its "title" and "desc" objects, then object "2" etc.

Comment: I have solved my problem using Bruce's solution. Thanks for your help anyway. =)