# how to parse json with special key by Gson

Tags: java, gson

This is  the json String:

```
{
  new : "",
  xx : "yy",
  ......
}
```

java, for the key `new`,

```
private String new;
```

is illegal.

How to write my domain Class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796662/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-key-and-value-in-android refer this

Comment: That is not valid JSON.  Go to json.org to learn the syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: this JSON is from server ,and i can not do anything.And i need to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to write my domain Class?

Since `new` is a keyword in java hence you can't use it as variable name. You can use annotation [`SerializedName`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) that that indicates this member should be serialized to JSON with the *provided name value as its field name*.

Sample Domain class:

```
class NewDetail{
    @SerializedName(value="new")
    private String newValue;
    private String xx;
    // getter & setter
}
```