# parsing json using Gson which has objects with same field name

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a json file which has following structure:

```
{
"Otions": true
"Plastic": ""
"Houses": {
   7: {
   "name": "Akash Bhawan"
   "MemBers": 3
   "children": 1
   }-
   8: {
   "name": "Ashiyana"
   "memBers": 4
   "children": 2
   }-
   9: {
  "name": "Faruks Nest"
  "memBers": 5
  "children": 1
  }-
```

The objects inside Houses are variable and can increase or decrease accordingly  and also change names.
How ever the fieds "name", "members", "children" are the only fields and will always be there

i am using gson to parse

```
@SerializedName("Otions")
private String Options;
@SerializedName("Plastic")
private String plastics;
@SerializedName("Houses")
private Houses houses;
```

i want to know if there is a way we can i can store differently named objects in a hashtable or some other way?

Comment: You might look into `names()` or `keys()` method of the `JSONObject`. I don't remember which ones gets your the keys (which will be "8" and "9" in your case).

Comment: take a look at this [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796662/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-key-and-value-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the structure then you have to make house as `Hashmap` of `int` to `object`. For Example:-

```
HashMap<int, Object> House;
```

And that object will have elements like name, memBers, details.

Comment: Do you mean JSONObject instead of Object ? I can't imagine an object having elements without a type

Comment: @Prim mean create a class with those three element and object of that class.

Comment: @TusharSaha it worked because above you have key-value pair, Where key is 7,8, 9 which are integers and value is { "name": "Akash Bhawan",
   "MemBers": 3, "children": 1 } which is an object, it is as simple as that.

Comment: @TusharSaha even if you want to go with an unnecessary HashMap-like solution, I'd suggest you to use `SparseArray`. You will avoid auto-boxing this way.

Answer (score 0):

Houses should be a map like this.

private HashMap houses.

Since the 3: indicates an index-structure. Gson will create the nested objects as needed.

Comment: List or array wont work as there are objects inside it

Comment: What should be key and value in the hashmap

Comment: '3' is the key and the "House"-object will be the value. This will be inserted by GSON.

Answer (score 0):

Please make "house" as bunch of array instead of objects.

```
{
    "Options": true,
    "Plastics": "",
    "house": [{
        "name": "Akash Bhawan",
        "MemBers": 3,
        "children": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Ashiyana",
        "memBers": 4,
        "children": 2
    }, {
        "name": "Faruks Nest",
        "memBers": 5,
        "children": 1
    }]
}
```

Comment: i cannot change the structure of json

Comment: it is coming from backend i cant change it

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like (as said in my comment):

```
JSONObject jsonHouses = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Houses");
Iterator<String> keys = jsonHouses.keys(); //this will be array of "7", "8", "9"

if (keys.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject singleHouseObject = jsonHouses.getJSONObject(keys.next());
    //now do whatever you want to do with singleHouseObject.
    //this is the object which has "name", "MemBers", "children"
}
```