# Parsing Json dynamically.

Tags: android, json, parsing, setter, getter

I am working on json currently in android, but now i follow getter and setter methods to parse json. For example. if there are 5 fields in json string, so create 5 getter and setter methods in one class and accordingly parse the string.

But now in future if one more field increases in json string, then again i need to add one more getter and setter method in that class. 
So my question is can we parse json without getter setter, without any class? so that if json changes in future it can be handled well without adding new getter and setter method. 
Please let me know the dynamic way to handle json.

Comment: you can get your getter and setter easily try [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: Are you parsing directly or using Gson/Jackson?

Comment: I don't want getter setter methods logic. right now I use JSONObject to parse the json field

Comment: @theblitz Gson also need getter setter methods right?

Comment: use Jackson....see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796662/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-key-and-value-in-android

Comment: @user3530687 Gson doesn't require getters and setters.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 In my opinion Gson is better for a number of reasons. The two main ones are 1. It has been adopted by Google as the de-facto Json parser. 2. Benchmarks show that Gson is much faster for data that is small to medium size (which is what you usually have in an android app). Jackson is faster for large Json data streams.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  these web site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

for creating a class if in future any field increase just put the json in that it will automatically create a class for you .