# How to convert Dynamic nested JSON to JAVA Object in android with GSON?

Tags: android, json, dynamic, gson

I'm trying to display following JSON to my RecyclerView and perform action accordingly. Now, the problem is, How can I access each key from JSON object and values inside keys. Do I need to store them in Java Objects with POJO or Array? I'm getting following response from server so I don't want to store them statically, I want to store it dynamically.

I looked for solution for the same but most of them include JSONArray and my response doesn't include any JSONArray. It includes key and JSONObject as a value. I don't know java as well, I am webdev, I've been looking for it for a day now.

```
{
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "result": {
        "17": {
            "key1": "3",
            "key2": "111111",
            "key3": "aaa",
            "key4": "sss",
            "key5": "aaa@asd.com",
            "key6": "1122334455",
            "key7": "2017-12-11",
            "key7": "something",
            "key9": "location"
        },
        "18": {
            "key1": "3",
            "key2": "111111",
            "key3": "aaa",
            "key4": "sss",
            "key5": "aaa@asd.com",
            "key6": "1122334455",
            "key7": "2017-12-11",
            "key7": "something",
            "key9": "location"
        },
        "19": {
            "key1": "3",
            "key2": "111111",
            "key3": "aaa",
            "key4": "sss",
            "key5": "aaa@asd.com",
            "key6": "1122334455",
            "key7": "2017-12-11",
            "key7": "something",
            "key9": "location"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have Result JSONObject in a string,

```
  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                String status = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject responseCode = response.getJSONObject("response");
                    status = responseCode.getString("result");
                    //Todo

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    defaultView.setText("Json Error");
                }

                defaultView.setText(status);

            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796987/2633909

Comment: Not a chance you're using Retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I guess your example `"key7": "something"` should actually be `"key8.."`.

Gson can parse any valid JSON to a `LinkedTreeMap` that you can then loop any way you want. However, your response seems to be static to some extent so you can create a DTO to make accessing values a bit easier. This DTO could be like:

```
@Getter
public class ResponseWrapper {
    @Getter
    public static class Response {
        private Integer status;
        private Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> result;       
    }
    private Response response;
}
```

With this kind of a DTO you could then do foo example (and assuming no Java8 & Streams):

```
Response rw = new Gson().fromJson(RESPONSE_JSON, ResponseWrapper.class).getResponse();
Set<Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>>> entries = rw.getResult().entrySet();
for(Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> e : entries) {
    Object o = e.getValue().get("key1");
    // do somethigs
}
```

If your example's result keys (17,18,19) contain a fixed set of keys - so just from key1 to key9 with the same data types - you could create a separate DTO for that also, like:

```
@Getter
public class ResultItem {
    private Long key1;
    private Long key2;
    private String key3;
    private String key4;
    private String key5;
    private Long key6;
    private Date key7;
    private String key8;
    private String key9;
}
```

and then your access to values might be just a bit more type safe, for example:

```
for(Entry<Integer, ResultItem> e : entries) {
    Long longKey1 = e.getValue().getKey1();
    // do somethings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the begging you can need to create your POJO's ,this site to create your POJO [JsonToPojoLink](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

then you can use GSON like this:

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
    ResponsePOJO responsePOJO;
    responsePOJO= gson.fromJson(response.toString(),ResponsePOJO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a response of result object with multiple object values.
So, you can simply apply a logic behind like,

```
JSONObject responseCode = response.getJSONObject("response");  
JSONObject resultCode = responseCode.getJSONObject("result");

    if(resultCode.length >0){
        for(int i=0;i<resultCode;i++){
            JSONObject listCode = resultCode.getJSONObject(i);
            String keyVal_1=listCode.getString("key1");
//store keyVal_1 in your arrayList and other keys 
//it will work till the dynamically generated last object you store.
        }
    }
```