# JSON - deserialization of dynamic object using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Let's imagine I have a Java class of the type:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public String par1;
   public Object par2;
}
```

Then I have this:

```
String json = "{"par1":"val1","par2":{"subpar1":"subval1"}}";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder.create();
MyClass mClass = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

The `par2` JSON is given to me from some other application and I don't ever know what are it's parameter names, since they are dynamic.

My question is, what Class type should `par2` variable on MyClass be set to, so that the JSON String variable is correctly deserialized to my class object?

Thanks

Comment: Are you tied to Gson? Your use case could be handled much better with a free-form JSON processor like json-simple (http://code.google.com/p/json-simple).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener) from GSON User Guide:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
   public String par1;
   public T par2;
}
```

To deserialize it:

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Myclass<Foo>>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I don't think this helps the OP. He does not know what type the object is going to be before he performs the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer from Kevin Dolan on this SO question: [How can I convert JSON to a HashMap using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/convert-json-to-hashmap-using-gson-in-java)

Note, it isn't the accepted answer and you'll probably have to modify it a bit. But it's pretty awesome.

Alternatively, ditch the type safety of your top-level object and just use hashmaps and arrays all the way down. Less modification to Dolan's code that way.

Answer (score -1):

if you object has dynamic name inside lets say this one:

```
{
    "Includes": {
        "Products": {
            "blablabla": {
                "CategoryId": "this is category id",
                "Description": "this is description",
                ...
}
```

you can serialize it with:

`MyFunnyObject data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyFunnyObject.class);`

```
@Getter
@Setter
class MyFunnyObject {
    Includes Includes;
    class Includes {
        Map<String, Products> Products;
        class Products {
            String CategoryId;
            String Description;
        }
    }
}
```

later you can access it:

`data.getIncludes().get("blablabla").getCategoryId()`

Answer (score -6):

this code:
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder.create();`

should be:

```
Gson gson=new Gson()
```

i think(if you are parsing a json doc).

Comment: Your suggestion is exactly equivalent to the original code.  This would do nothing.