# Deserialization of object of class that have different constructors with Gson

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

Here explained deserialization for classes with Generic types
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829656/4553806. 
Now suppese we I have some situation, but my Class has two constructors with different count of parameters.

```
    class TestClass(val par1:String, val par2:String)
    class TestClass(val par1:String)
```

So I know that my object is type of TestClass, but I don't know with which constructor it initialized.

**How to deserialize?**

Using this way

```
val fooType = object : TypeToken<Myclass<String>>() {}.type;
gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

or this

```
val fooType = object : TypeToken<Myclass<String, String>>() {}.type);
gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

could cause exception if objects fields count doesn't match.

If any one has experience with this case, please mention it here.

Comment: Deserialize to Map

Answer (score 0):

GSON is very easy to use, just set your serializedName and use the GSON converter to populate it. Here is a simple tutorial to follow.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_quick_guide.htm