# Android: Convert web service json output into java hashmap

Tags: android, json, hashmap

I have the following output, where wsResponse.get("result").toString() 
= {"status":1,"result":{"2011":102003,"2010":100003,"2009":98723,"2008":129023}}

I'll like to create a hashmap where the years are the key.

How will i be able to populate the hashmap?

Comment: You might start here. Hope it helps!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/convert-json-to-hashmap-using-gson-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to have a hashmap? Android has the org.json library, so you can do something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(wsResponse.get("result").toString());
```

If you check out [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), you can use JSONObject just like a hashmap. You can call `get(String key)` to get the value for a year.

If you must have a hashmap, you can iterate through the JSONObject and put the keys and values in the hashmap.

Comment: Yeah, this might help, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/convert-json-to-hashmap-using-gson-in-java

Comment: I've got the json object:
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json = (JSONObject)wsResponse.get("result");

But didn't quite manage to iterate through the key value pairs. Is there an iterator for JSON like that of hashmap?

Comment: Yes. json.keys() will return an iterator for the key names.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).