# Merge multiple Collection<String> into one JSON String using GSON

Tags: java, json, collections, gson

Is there a way to merge different String-Collections into one JSON 'String'?
I would like to have a JSON String that looks like this:

```
{"vendor":[Sun, HP, IBM],"product":[bla, bla, bla],"availability":[high, mid, low],"capacity":[bla, bla, bla], ...}
```

This is a part of my Java Code:

```
Collection<String> vendor = bh.getAllVendors();
Collection<String> product = bh.getProductsForVendor(vendor);
Collection<String> availability = bh.getAllAvailabilities();
Collection<String> capacity = bh.getCapacityForVendor(vendor);
Collection<String> signaling = bh.getSignalingForVendor(vendor);
Collection<String> backup = bh.getBackupForVendor(vendor);

Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be easiest if you add them to a map:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("vendor", vendor);
    map.put("product", product);
    //etc

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(map));
```

produces
    `{"product":["bla","bla","bla"],"vendor":["Sun","IBM","HP"]}`

Comment: Nice. Only trouble is, if later you want to deserialize it, you either need to define a class with 'vendor', 'product' etc as attributes, or you need to write a custom deserializer. More details in one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/convert-json-to-hashmap-using-gson-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class:

```
Class MyJSONObject
  {
    Collection<String> vendor;
    Collection<String> product;
    Collection<String> availability;
    //...
    //...
  }
```

Then assign your data to those attributes in an instance of `MyJSONObject`.

Then serialize that instance:

```
gson.toJson (myJSONObjectInstance);
```

Read the 'Object Examples' section of [this GSON documentation](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I prefer it to the accepted answer.