# Gson to HashMap

Tags: java, android, gson

Is there a way to convert a String containing json to a HashMap, where every key is a json-key and the value is the value of the json-key? The json has no nested values. I am using the Gson lib.

For example, given JSON:

```
{
"id":3,
"location":"NewYork"
}
```

resulting HashMap:

```
<"id", "3">
<"location", "NewYork">
```

Thanks

Comment: @MattBall Seems a pretty unfriendly welcome to a new user. Looking at the answer, it is not at all obvious, and hardly simple. Who uses `TypeToken` for anything, ever?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "a pretty unfriendly welcome." Did I post & forget about an abrasive comment that was just deleted? To answer your question: I don't use GSON, so I don't use `TypeToken`, but I **do** use [the equivalent in Jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) pretty darn frequently.

Comment: @MattBall You had a comment about asking what had been tried (with a link) and saying that the question was pretty simple.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html), as per [the GSON FAQ](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type stringStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String,String> map = gson.fromJson(json, stringStringMap);
```

No casting. No unnecessary object creation.

Comment: What's the import for Type? It gives dozens of options.

Comment: @ThePixelPony read [the `TypeToken#getType()` JavaDoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) for the FQCN of the return type.

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.Type stringStringMap = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();`

Comment: This works, but your value type is not respected -- everything is treated as strings. If you change it to `Map<String, Object>` then you'll actually get properly typed values.

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz the question subtly suggests that the values should be strings as well, but sure.

Comment: @Matt Ball Ahh yes, I see the desired output. I was looking at the actual JSON input.

Comment: @MattBall I have a similar question with Gson [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029313/how-to-parse-json-into-a-map-using-gson). I wanted to see if you can help me out. I do have a solution but the problem is it looks very messy just to parse a JSON into a Map.

Comment: For `Map<String, Integer>` Its converting to Double. this is what I am using `Map<String, Integer> typeMap = Maps.newHashMap(); new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, typeMap.getClass());`

Comment: `new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, new TypeToken<Map<String, Integer>>(){}.getType().getClass());`
is converting to `Double` not `Integer`.

Answer (score 9):

If I use the TypeToken solution with a Map<**Enum**, Object> I get "duplicate key: null".

The best solution for me is:

```
String json = "{\"id\":3,\"location\":\"NewYork\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map = (Map<String, Object>)gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
```

Result:

```
{id=3.0, location=NewYork}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like:

```
private static class MyMap extends HashMap<String,String> {};
...
MyMap map = gson.fromJson(json, MyMap.class);
```