# json array in hashmap using google gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am new with Gson and I am trying to parse array of object in a `Hashmap`, but I am getting `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3`.

My code is

```
Map<String, String> listOfCountry = new HashMap<String, String>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType();
listOfCountry = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
```

and JSON is

```
[
  {"countryId":"1","countryName":"India"},
  {"countryId":"2","countryName":"United State"}
]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example of the Map structure you'd like to end up with?

Comment: First go to json.org and spend ten minutes (that all it takes) to learn the JSON syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of objects, not anything resembling a `HashMap`.

If you mean you're trying to convert that to a `List` of `HashMap`s ... then that's what you need to do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String, String>>>(){}.getType();
List<HashMap<String, String>> listOfCountry = 
    gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
```

**Edit to add from comments below:**

If you would like to deserialize to an array of `Country` POJOs (which is really the better approach), it's as simple as:

```
class Country {
    public String countryId;
    public String countryName;
}
...
Country[] countryArray = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, Country[].class);
```

That said, it's really better to use a `Collection`:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Country>>(){}.getType();
List<Country> countryList = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, listType);
```

Comment: No i just need to put all data in to hashmap. not a list of hashmap in a single hashmap

Comment: Well, since your JSON isn't a hashmap, and your data isn't anything that you could "just put in a hashmap" ... your question makes absolutely no sense then.

Comment: when i try to get it in a country class array all field are null Type listType = new TypeToken<country[]>() {}.getType();      country[] carray=gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType)

Comment: "abosultely no sense" is a bit harsh, you can simply put the keys and values in a hashmap. the keys countryId and countryName and the values being the json string or an object. Yeah creating a pojo is nice, but this can be used as a intermediary. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14944513/106261

Answer (score 2):

After reading what @dimo414 and @Brian Roach said, if you still want to get a map out of your json structure, you can achieve by doing this:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(type, new JsonDeserializer<HashMap<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (JsonElement element : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();

            signals.put(jsonObject.get("countryId").getAsString(), jsonObject.get("countryName").getAsString());
        }

        return map;
    }
}).create();

HashMap<String, String> countries = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, type);
```

But at that point you could just parse your json into a JsonArray and loop through it making your map.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to create a mapping of `countryId`s to `countryName`s, correct?  This can be done in Gson, but really isn't what it is designed for.  Gson is primarily intended translate JSON into equivalent Java objects (e.g. an array into a List, an object into an Object or a Map, etc.) and not for transforming arbitrary JSON into arbitrary Java.

If it's possible, the best thing for you to do would be to refactor your JSON.  Consider the following format:

```
{
  "1": "India",
  "2": "United State"
}
```

It's less verbose, easier to read, and most notably, easy to parse with Gson:

```
Type countryMapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer,String>>(){}.getType();
Map<Integer,String> countryMap = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), countryMapType);
```

---

If you cannot edit your JSON syntax, you'll have to manually parse the JSON data into the structure you're trying to create, which will be somewhat tedious and involved.  Best to read up on the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer) to learn how.

As an aside, you call your `Map<String, String>` object `listOfCountry`, which is a confusing name - is it a map or a list?  Avoid using names like "list" for objects that aren't lists.  In this case I would suggest either `countries` or `countryMap`.