# Parsing json variable objects with same name using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Hi I want to parse the json

```
 {
        "entityType":"Account",


        "values":[
                {
                    "name":"accountType",
                    "type":"lookup",
                    "typeinfo":{"entity":"lov", "filter":"LOV_ACCOUNT_TYPE"}
                },
                {
                    "name":"irstSubType",
                    "type":"lookup",
                    "typeinfo":{"entity":"lov", "filter":"LOV_ACCOUNT_TYPE"}
                },
                {
                    "name":"accountStatus",
                    "type":"lookup",
                    "typeinfo":{"entity":"lov", "filter":"LOV_ACCOUNT_STATUS"}
                },
                {
                    "name":"name",
                    "type":"string",
                    "typeinfo":{"width":80}
                },
                {
                    "name":"updated",
                    "type":"datetime",
                    "typeinfo":{"format":"dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:ss"}
                }
          ]
    }
```

So here typeinfo object implementation is changing.. any suggessions how does Gson library accomodate this? Interface does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Value**

```
public class Value {
private String name;
private String type;    
private  TypeInfo typeinfo;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public TypeInfo getTypeinfo() {
    return typeinfo;
}
}
```

**MyGson**

```
public class MyGson {
private String entityType;
private List<Value> values;

public String getEntityType() {
    return entityType;
}
public List<Value> getValues() {
    return values;
}
}
```

**TypeInfo**

```
public class TypeInfo {

private String format;
private String entry;
private String filter;

public String getFormat() {
    return format;
}

public String getEntry() {
    return entry;
}

public String getFilter() {
    return filter;
}
}
```

**Launcher**

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    MyGson myGson = gson.fromJson(str, MyGson.class);

    List<Value> values = myGson.getValues();


    for(Value value : values){

        str = value.getTypeinfo().getFormat();


        printValues("format", value.getTypeinfo().getFormat());
        printValues("entry", value.getTypeinfo().getEntry());
        printValues("filter", value.getTypeinfo().getFilter());
        //....
    }




}

private static void printValues(String key, String data){
    if(data != null){
        System.out.println(key + ": " + data);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
filter: LOV_ACCOUNT_TYPE
filter: LOV_ACCOUNT_TYPE
filter: LOV_ACCOUNT_STATUS
format: dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:ss
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for the solution, so  the issue is I want to keep it generic tomorrow if typeinfo object changes I want to keep a different implementation of it and do not want to keep on appending to the same typeinfo.. is there any way to do so using gson? first answer is more generic but it takes some efforts to covert all the jsonobjects in respective java objects

Comment: if json changed and lets say `entity` gone  in your class `entity` will be automatically `null`. easy to handle it. On thoer hand if new value has been added to json, you still dosnt get it. Crash can happen only id they change type of value. But better to change class instead change code

Answer (score 0):

Despite the other answers, it is not a good idea to have a field for each of the possible variables in typeinfo, as two fields could have same name but different types.

What you really want to do, is to turn the data from typeinfo into a Map<String, Object>.

This is difficult in Gson, but it is possible using a deserializer - see Kevin's answer for an example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4799594/1660737

Comment: Yes this post might be helpful here.

Comment: Sounds great! You can mark this answer as 'accepted' if it suits your needs, so others quickly can see that it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
        String s = "...json string ..";
        JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonparser.parse(s);
        JSONArray values = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("values");

        for(int i=0; i< values.size(); i++){
            JSONObject value = (JSONObject)values.get(i);
            JSONObject typeInfo = (JSONObject)value.get("typeinfo");
            Iterator it = typeInfo.keySet().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                Object key = it.next();
                System.out.println("KEY:" + key + " VALUE:" + typeInfo.get(key));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can write also `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s)`