# How to get the value form json object inside form another json object where keys aye dynimic

Tags: android, json, android-json

I want to get the value from below json response. I am able to get the value from first key but not anther key object. I want to get the value of all url but no of url is dynamic and key too. Below is json response:

**I am able to get the value of body, title and created_date**

```
{
"17": {
    "27": {
        "url": "some text here 1"
    },
    "28": {
        "url": "some text here 12"
    },
    "29": {
        "url": "some text here 123"
    },
    "title": "some text goes here",
    "body": "Some text goes here",
    "created_date": "1395386881"
 }
}
```

Code what i am trying is below:

```
try {
        json = new JSONTokener(jsonNewsResponse).nextValue();
        if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;
            Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                nid = String.valueOf(keys.next());
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject(nid);
                attributeValue = jsonObj.getString(attributeName);
                    List<String> listitems = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Iterator<?> key = jsonObj.keys();
                    while (key.hasNext()) {

                        String fid = String.valueOf(key.next());
                        System.out.println("FID"+fid);
                        System.out.println("FID"+fid);
                        System.out.println("FID"+fid);
                        System.out.println("FID"+fid);
                        JSONObject jObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject(fid);
                        listitems.add(jObject.getString("url"));
                    }
                    attachments = listitems.toArray(new String[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: consider looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
    JSONObject Jobj;
    try {
        Jobj = new JSONTokener(jsonNewsResponse).nextValue();
        if (Jobj instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) Jobj;
            Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String nid = String.valueOf(keys.next());
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject(nid);
                    Iterator<?> key = jsonObj.keys();
                    while (key.hasNext()) {
                        String fid = String.valueOf(key.next());
                        Log.v("fid--",""+fid);

                        if( jsonObj.get(fid) instanceof JSONObject){
                            JSONObject jObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject(fid);
                            String url = jObject.getString("url");
                                    Log.v("url--",""+url);
                        }else{
                                String fidfadd = jsonObj.getString(fid);
                                Log.v("fidfadd--",""+fidfadd);
                            }
                     }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
Map<String,Object> myMap=gson.fromJson( "your_json_string_after_getting_first_body", Map.class );
```

map's key = your json object's key. And value is jsonObjects that contains keys and urls. And don't use your whole json into it. Just for below part.

```
"27": {
    "url": "some text here 1"
},
"28": {
    "url": "some text here 12"
},
"29": {
    "url": "some text here 123"
},
```

but of course you can extend it whatever you want. [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: If our nearly simultaneous answers aren't proof of how he should do it, I don't know what is!

Comment: Can you be more clarify ?

Comment: I'm saying that we both told him "use Gson", so clearly he should use Gson. I just thought it was amusing that we said practically the same thing.

Comment: ooh :) yeap because truth is truth in every language or everywhere :)

Comment: i have added GSON library in my project don't know how to use them. Could you Please explain this. @CorayThan

Comment: please examine here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/convert-json-to-hashmap-using-gson-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
YourObjectsClass yourObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, YourObjectsClass.class)
```

Now that I look at it more closely, I'm not sure that json can map to a very good object model in Java. You have fields with the key "27" on the same tier as fields with real String names, like "title", but they have different types of objects as their values (some have a string, some have a complex object that contains one field with the name "url"). Java field names cannot start with a number, though, so you can't make a normal Java class out of it, and you can't make a map out of it either, unless it is a map that accepts only `<Object>` as its value, which isn't ideal.

So I would recommend you fix your Json, then make a model class to represent it.

Comment: @user31blahblah There are many resources and tutorials about how to use the Gson library. I linked you to their webpage, where they have a user guide and an API. You can also google "How to use gson" and get tons of examples. But really, all you should need is in that one liner I wrote above. You may want to save your `Gson` and reference it elsewhere, but that's the basics.