# Parsing JSON array

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using GSON for parsing JSON response.

Unfortunately the WebApi on the server has quite untypical JSON objects.

I need to parse Attachments array from this JSON (there can be more attachments):

```
{"htmlMessage":"text","Attachments":{"8216096_0":{"content":null,"filename":"plk.jpg","contentType":"image/jpeg","contentDisposition":"attachment","size":86070}}}
```

Where `8216096_0` is attachments id.

I can't do it with Gson (or I don't know how) so I'm trying to do it with JSONObjects:

```
// parse attachments
JSONObject attachmentsJson = result.getJSONObject("Attachments");
```

Then I have one JSONObject with an array of attachments, but I don't know how to get them to the ArrayList from JSONObject because the key value isn't static but generated id..

Thank you

**//EDIT:** 
Thanks to all guys for helping! My final solution looks like this especially thanks to @Jessie A. Morris and his final answer!

```
List<AttachmentModel> attachmentsList = new ArrayList<AttachmentModel>();
for( Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> attachment : attachments.entrySet()) {
    AttachmentModel attachmentModel = new AttachmentModel();
    attachmentModel = gson.fromJson(attachment.getValue().getAsJsonObject().toString(), AttachmentModel.class);;
    attachmentModel.setmUid(attachment.getKey());
    attachmentsList.add(attachmentModel);
 }
```

Comment: It is not an array. You can parse it to map instead, where `8216096_0` is the key.

Comment: Oh I was thinking about it, but I can not imagine how to do it exactly. Can you give me little hint please? I'm desperate, their api is just strange

Comment: Take a look at:http://stackoverflow.com/a/12296567/1651233

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've changed my example a little bit and am certain that this does work correctly (I just tested it):

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by jessie on 14-07-09.
 */
public class TestGson {
    private static String JSON = "{\"htmlMessage\":\"text\",\"Attachments\":{\"8216096_0\":{\"content\":null,\"filename\":\"plk.jpg\",\"contentType\":\"image/jpeg\",\"contentDisposition\":\"attachment\",\"size\":86070}}}\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(JSON).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject attachments = json.getAsJsonObject("Attachments");

        List<JsonObject> attachmentsList = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
        for( Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> attachment : attachments.entrySet()) {
            attachmentsList.add(attachment.getValue().getAsJsonObject());
        }

        System.out.println("attachmentsList at the end? " + attachmentsList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but it doesn't work neither.. on line `attachmentsList.add(attachmentsJson.get(key))` returns Object instead of JSONObject and then when I fix it to `getJSONObject` it says that `attachmentsJson` foreach not applicable to type 'java.util.Iterator'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if this really works:

```
final Map<String,JSONObject> attachmentsJson = (Map<String,JSONObject>) jsonArray.getJSONObject("Attachments");
for(String attachmentId : attachmentsJson.keySet()) {
  final JSONObject attachmentJson = attachmentsJson.get(attachmentId);
}
```

Comment: Thank yo. I like your solution but unfortunately I'm getting an exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.Map` on first line where you are trying to cast JSON to Map

Comment: ok, then this is the wrong answer. See @Jessie A. Morris for the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The "Attachments" obj in your example is not an array.**

Json arrays are denoted by [....].

"Attachments" is a Json object holding an inner object called "8216096_0".

so to get the inner values do as follows:

```
JSONObject attachmentsJson = result.getJSONObject("Attachments");
JSONObject inner = attachmentsJson.getJSONObject("8216096_0");

// and interrogate the inner obj:
String content = inner.getString("content");
String filename = inner.getString("filename");
```

Finally, and for example sake, I will add the code for **processing a (real) Json array**:

```
{"htmlMessage":"text",
   "Attachments":[{"8216096_0":{"content":null,"filename":"plk.jpg","contentType":"image/jpeg",
                  "contentDisposition":"attachment","size":86070}},                  
                 {"8216096_1":{"content":null,"filename":"plk.jpg","contentType":"image/jpeg",
                    "contentDisposition":"attachment","size":86070}},  
              ]
   }
```

It will go like this:

```
JSONArray attachmentsJson = result.getJSONObject("Attachments");
int len = attachmentsJson.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    JSONObject elem =  attachmentsJson.getJSONObject(i); // <------ get array element 
    JSONObject inner = elem.getJSONObject("8216096_0");   
    // and interrogate the inner obj:
    String content = inner.getString("content");
    String filename = inner.getString("filename");
}
```

..Or similar, depending on your Json's exact format.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. But there can be more attachments in others emails, so I have to solve it differently

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have problem with `attachmentsJson.getJSONObject(i);` the getJSONObject(String) instead of int i... or am I missing something? And I don't understand to this: `elem.getJSONObject("8216096_0");` how can u use 8216096_0 which I don't know at this time?