# How to serialize json string using GSON and extract key and value from it?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to parse my JSON string using GSON and extract key:value pairs from a simple json string and load it in the map. As of now I am using `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` to do that. Now I am trying to do the same thing using GSON.

Below is my json string `jsonstringA`-

```
{"description":"Hello World.","hostname":"abc1029.dc3.host.com","ipaddress":"100.671.1921.219","hostid":"/tt/rt/v2/dc3/111","file_timestamp":"20140724","software_version":"v13","commit_hash":"abcdefg"}
```

Now I need to serialize the above JSON string and extract below fields from json stringg and put it in the `map m` as key value pair. Meaning in the map it should be `description` as key and `Hello World` as the value. Similarly for others as well.

```
public static final Set<String> MAPPING_FIELDS = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
        "description", "hostname", "ipaddress", "hostid", "software_version"));

private final static JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


parseJSONData(jsonstringA, MAPPING_FIELDS);

public Map<String, String> parseJSONData(String jsonStr, Set<String> listOfFields) {
    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(jsonStr);
        org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            for (String field : listOfFields) {
                String value = (String) jsonObject.get(field);
                m.put(field, value);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // log exception here
    }
    return m;
}
```

How do I use GSON here to do the same thing?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson#answer-4799594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Just create a ***POJO*** that have same variable as used in JSON string.

Have a look in Java Doc of [Gson#fromJson(Reader,Type)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29)

sample code:

```
class ClientDetail {
    private String description;
    private String hostname;
    private String ipaddress;
    private String hostid;
    private String file_timestamp;;
    private String software_version;
    private String commit_hash;
    // getter & setter
}

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("json.txt")));
ClientDetail data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, ClientDetail.class);
```

---

You can convert it into `Map` as well using [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to convert it into expected type.

sample code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("json.txt")));
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, type);
```

Comment: I have the gson string coming on the fly. How to handle this situation where I don't have a `json.txt` here??

Comment: Explore more on overloadded method of 'Gson.fromJson()'