# Json to HashMap

Tags: java, json, apache, http, gson

I have the following as a json output, how do I convert it to a HashMap using Gson:

```
{
    "result": {
        "haystack": [
            "SvqFd",
            "ucR3Y",
            "AzVB0",
            "DrDQL",
            "gc8LQ",
            "JqKdK",
            "9ZE4g",
            "820gw",
            "ekWkr",
            "qgDrR",
            "ENpyZ",
            "lf4b8",
            "SZsUt",
            "YO0cQ",
            "CD1O0",
            "Rvw8t",
            "euSC0",
            "3oemT",
            "6bUgC",
            "m8pFK"
        ],
        "needle": "lf4b8"
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
Type stringArrayMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String[]>>(){}.getType(); 
Map<String,String[]> theCollection = gson.fromJson(output, stringArrayMap);
```

Edit:
Each time I get this json output,its content is unique but same structure.

`ANSWER`

Answers and suggestions below worked but I played around with those and figured something else that worked as well;

```
Type stringStringObjectMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>(){}.getType(); 
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> theDictionary = gson.fromJson(output, stringStringObjectMap);
```

Comment: Hope the below link helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Parse `Json` String to create `JSONObject`.

2.) `Iterate` over JsonObject to create Map.

you might get [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html) what you want