# Android JSON multiple pairs parse

Tags: android, json

I have a JSONObject like this

{"message":{"context":"ws","data":"","id":"12345","http_accept":"json","method":"GET","search_key":"cat"},"response":{"1":"cat", "2":"catte"},"status":"OK","code":200}.

I am trying to get the result of a search webservice. I want the value of the pairs from the "response" key to add them to an ArrayList.

For example, from this "response" I want "cat" and "catte". How can I parse to get them?

Comment: how abt parsing them in collection and serach on it

Comment: or try to use Gson, look into example how gson works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JSON `Iterator` to loop over all the keys and collect the `response` values.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonInput);
JSONObject resp = root.getJSONObject("response");

List<String> respList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Iterator<String> iterator = resp.keys(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    respList.add(resp.getString(key));
    System.out.println(key + " = " + resp.getString(key));
}
System.out.println(respList);
```

***Output :***

> 1 = cat
>  2 = catte
>  [cat, catte]

Answer (score 0):

"response"s structure is **map**. You can easily parse it with Gson. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson)