# Gson parse error while parsing a JSON object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse this JSON:

```
{
  "Aatrox": {
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "id": "Aatrox",
    "key": "266",
    "name": "Aatrox",
    "title": "the Darkin Blade"
  },
  "Ahri": {
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "id": "Ahri",
    "key": "103",
    "name": "Ahri",
    "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"
  },
  "Akali": {
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "id": "Akali",
    "key": "84",
    "name": "Akali",
    "title": "the Fist of Shadow"
  },
  ....
}
```

As you can see the elements all have the same attributes, so I want to parse them as a list of elements, here's the class I'm using:

```
public class CampeonBO {

private String version;
private String id;
private String key;
private String name;
private String title;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to parse it with Gson

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<CampeonBO>>(){}.getType();
List<CampeonBO> campeones = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, type);
```

And I'm getting the error:

> ```
> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
> ```

Which is obviously because I don´t have an array in my JSON, I have 3 attributes "Aatrox, Ahri, Akali", but they all have the same attributes, so how can I parse them as a list using Gson?

Comment: You have a map of `String`s to `CampeonBO`s, not a list.

Comment: That's right @dimo414 , that's the solution, using a Map<String,CampeonBO>. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You're telling Gson to parse data into a `List`, meaning Gson expects to parse a JSON array:

[image: JSON Array format]

However the JSON you're trying to parse is in fact a JSON object:

[image: JSON Object format]

In general, the Gson way to parse a JSON object is to parse it into a dedicated Java type, as you're doing with `CampeonBO`.  However a JSON object is also conceptually a mapping, and therefore you can use a `Map` as your parse `Type` if you're trying to parse a JSON object with arbitrary keys and the same type for all values.

Once you have a `Map`, you can call [`Map.values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) to get a `Collection` of the map's values (which you can then put into a `List` if you need).

See [How can I convert JSON to a HashMap using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson) for some examples.

Images from http://json.org/.

Comment: Thank you so much! i resolved my problem using a Map.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON,

```
{
"Aatrox": {
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "id": "Aatrox",
    "key": "266",
    "name": "Aatrox",
    "title": "the Darkin Blade"
},
"Akali": {
    "version": "5.2.1",
    "id": "Akali",
    "key": "84",
    "name": "Akali",
    "title": "the Fist of Shadow"
}
}
```

an array would  been :

```
   [
    {
        "version": "5.2.1",
        "id": "Aatrox",
        "key": "266",
        "name": "Aatrox",
        "title": "the Darkin Blade"
     },
    {
        "version": "5.2.1",
        "id": "Akali",
        "key": "84",
        "name": "Akali",
        "title": "the Fist of Shadow"
    }
  ]
```

please notice the **Square brackets**. So if possible,please modify your service

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I can´t modify the json so i can´t change it to square brackets.

Comment: its a string isnt it?you could modify the characters when they come in.If not.Then you need to modify your pojo to accept this input.Or manually parse the JSON

Comment: @LuisMiguel yes you are correct that json is incorrect otherwise `Type type = new TypeToken<List<CampeonBO>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<CampeonBO> campeones = new Gson().fromJson(s, type);` will work.