# Easiest way to set POJO data

Tags: java, android, gson

Hello I am looking the way to not setting all values from POJO class one by one. and setter must be invoked in one go.

I have this POJO data.

```
private int id;
private String newsfeedCategories;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String mobile;
private String sendNotifications;
private String zipcode;
private String uniounSupplier;
private String unionContractor;
private String password;
private String lastUpdate;
private String deviceType;
private String firstName;
private String unionRep;
private String local;
private String deviceToken;
private String unionLegislator;
private String gender;
private String unionCarpenter;
```

When I call web service I need to call setter for each value. Is there any other way to set whole data in better and efficiant way.

Below is my code to set POJO

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

            UserData response = new UserData(jObj);

            String json = gson.toJson(response);

            response = gson.fromJson(json, UserData.class);



            /* Data data1 = ParseManager.parseLoginResponse(result);

            UserManager.setLoginResponse(data1);

           Data d =  UserManager.getUer();*/

           /* Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            Data userData = (Data) bundle.getParcelable("email");*/

            //Log.e("email Id is","-----------------"+ userData.getEmail());
            // here to set the parser class and fetch the result

            Data data = new Data();

            data.setId(response.getData().getId());
            data.setFirstName(response.getData().getFirstName());
            data.setLastName(response.getData().getLastName());
            data.setMobile(response.getData().getMobile());
            data.setEmail(response.getData().getEmail());
            data.setZipcode(response.getData().getZipcode());
            data.setGender(response.getData().getGender());
            data.setPassword(response.getData().getPassword());
            data.setUnionCarpenter(response.getData().getUnionCarpenter());
            data.setUnionRep(response.getData().getUnionRep());
            data.setLocal(response.getData().getLocal());
            data.setUnionContractor(response.getData().getUnionContractor());
            data.setUnionLegislator(response.getData().getUnionLegislator());
            data.setUniounSupplier(response.getData().getUniounSupplier());
            data.setNewsfeedCategories(response.getData().getNewsfeedCategories());
            data.setSendNotifications(response.getData().getSendNotifications());
            data.setLastUpdate(response.getData().getLastUpdate());
```

Comment: what about using some network libraries like retrofit and gson converter or " gson.fromJson(string, Data .class);"

Comment: @quanlt I am using GSON for this.look at my code above.

Comment: So response.getData() contains the same POJO right?

Comment: @KshitijVyas What about  `Data data = response.getData();` ?

Comment: Userdata is a POJO itself Containing a JsonObject and a JSON Array. and DATA POJO contains the above mentioned values.

Comment: @Meet thnxx for the clue. Now I am not setting the DATA pojo. It was set through upper call. Foolish me.. If some body wants I ll share code.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a method in which you can set every values, and pass all values as params to this method.

You need to call only one method.

```
class YourPOJO {
    String var1, var2;
    int var3;
    .
    .
    .

    public void setData(String var1, String var2, int var3) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
        this.var3 = var3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Jackson `ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SourceBean source = ...;
TargetBean target = mapper.convertValue(source, TargetBean.class);
```

For best performance, it is best to do it with getters and setters. However, for code simplicity, you may use jackson

Alternately, If you don't mind using apache library, [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) from Apache Commons will handle this quite easily, using

`copyProperties(DestObject, SourceObject)`.

Comment: Yes I can understand this code is woking fine with no error and I can use it in app. But I m bit lazy to set the large data. What if I get 30 values from web service. I need to call 30 setters. Thats why looking for more improved way.

Comment: @KshitijVyas Aren't you looking for something similar to what is specified in the answer?

Comment: I implement the other way around. I ll give it a try. I had used JAKSON but found GSON more flexible to use that's why go with that. I ll give it a try for sure..Thnx for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a constructor with parameteres of your POJO and pass all your data in the parameter.

```
public class DummyPOJO{
private String data1;
private String data2;
.....

public DummyPOJO(String data1, String data2,....){
  this.data1=data1;
  this.data2=data2;
  ......
}   
}
```

If you are using any IDE like android studio you can directly create a constructor with parameters using `ALT+INS`

Answer (score 1):

use retrofit framwork.
so you can easyly manage data.and set it in to adapter or else , some code below.

```
 public interface RestClient {

 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("/order/order_list")
 void order(@Field("token") String token,
              @Field("page") String page,
              Callback<Home> callback);
}
```

first create inarface like above  than create finalwrapper class

```
public class FinalWrapper<T> {
public final T value;

public FinalWrapper(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

than other file create name with  RetrofitClient

```
 public class RetrofitClient {
private final static String TAG = RetrofitClient.class.getSimpleName();

private static FinalWrapper<RetrofitClient> helperWrapper;
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private final RestClient mRestOkClient;


private RetrofitClient() {
    // Rest client without basic authorization
    mRestOkClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(RestClient.class);
}

/**
 * @return
 */
public static RetrofitClient getInstance() {
    FinalWrapper<RetrofitClient> wrapper = helperWrapper;

    if (wrapper == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (helperWrapper == null) {
                helperWrapper = new FinalWrapper<>(new RetrofitClient());
            }
            wrapper = helperWrapper;
        }
    }
    return wrapper.value;
}

public RestClient getRestOkClient() {
    return mRestOkClient;
}
```

}

and finally create service ganarater

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
// No need to instantiate this class.
private ServiceGenerator() {
}

/**
 * @param serviceClass
 * @param <S>
 * @return
 */
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(Constant.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(Constant.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constant.BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));

    RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();


    return adapter.create(serviceClass);

}
}
```

and in your activity where you call service

```
  public void orderApi() {
    if (Utility.checkInternetConnection(getContext())) {
        if (db == 1) {
            getMessageUtil().showProgressDialog();
        }
        RetrofitClient.getInstance().getRestOkClient().
                order(VPreferences.getAccessToken(getContext()),
                        String.valueOf(page),
                        callback);
    }
}

private final retrofit.Callback callback = new retrofit.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object object, Response response) {
        getMessageUtil().hideProgressDialog();
        Home home = (Home) object;
        if(home.getResult().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            total = home.getOrders().getLast_page();
            homeOrderses.addAll(home.getOrders().getData());
            tabOrderAdapter = new TabOrderAdapter(getContext(), homeOrderses);
            if (db == 1) {
                rlOrder.setAdapter(tabOrderAdapter);
            } else {
                rlOrder.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "First Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity_.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.e("ERROR", error + "");
        getMessageUtil().hideProgressDialog();
    }
};
```

note put retrofit dependancy

Answer (score 1):

Create POJO class like this....

```
public class GetAllStudentModel {
private int id;
private String name;
private String branch;
private ArrayList<GetAllStudentModel> list;
private String sem;
private String photo_url;
private String email;
private String mobile;
private String dob;
public GetAllStudentModel(int id, String name, String branch, String sem, String photo_url,String mobile, String email,String dob) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.branch = branch;
    this.sem = sem;
    this.photo_url=photo_url;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.email = email;
    this.dob=dob;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBranch() {
    return branch;
}

public void setBranch(String branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}

public ArrayList<GetAllStudentModel> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<GetAllStudentModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public String getSem() {
    return sem;
}

public void setSem(String sem) {
    this.sem = sem;
}

public String getPhoto_url() {
    return photo_url;
}

public void setPhoto_url(String photo_url) {
    this.photo_url = photo_url;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}


}
```

and CALL this cunstructor like that..

```
 try{
     JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
     for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

          JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
          id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());
          name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_NAME);
          branch = jsonObject.getString(TAG_BRANCH);
          sem = jsonObject.getString("semester");
          photo_url=jsonObject.getString("photo");
          email=jsonObject.getString("email");
          mobile=jsonObject.getString("mobile");
          dob=jsonObject.getString("dob");
          getAllStudentModel = new GetAllStudentModel(id,name,branch,sem,photo_url,email,mobile,dob);
          list.add(getAllStudentModel);
     }
 }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the json to Map using Gson like below, quoted from
    [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson):-

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson("{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}", type);
```

You can use [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) to do this in a very clean way.

Populate a POJO from Map, [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#populate-java.lang.Object-java.util.Map-) for below method:-

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(Object bean, Map properties)
```

Map key should be the property or attribute name in POJO class, internally this method uses Java Reflection API to call the setter methods.

Your code will look like below:-

```
String json = gson.toJson(response);
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> jsonMap= gson.fromJson(json , type);
Data data = new Data();
BeanUtils.populate(data , jsonMap);
```

Comment: Hey I ll try this one. Can you fit this in my above code so that I can start with?

Comment: Edited my answer, 1. convert json to Map then 2. Map to Java Pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem is mapping one POJO to Other POJO.

You can use Dozer mapper for this.

[Dozer Example](https://dzone.com/articles/bean-manipulation-using-dozer)

Check [Dozer documentation here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html).