# Json text to RecyclerView in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

I need help with my RecyclerView. I have a atring array from my SQL Database which looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"0":{"order_number":"078","typ_first":"E3rft","typ_last":"Split","order_date_time":"2016-10-11 19:20:03"},"1":{"order_number":"166","typ_first":"E483f","typ_last":"Split_test","order_date_time":"2016-10-12 18:39:30"}}
```

In my RecyclerView I have the following fields:

- `order_number`
- `typ_all` (type first and last)
- `date`(only a date without time)

This is how I get my string array:

```
String plansData = plansPreferenceData.getString("plansPreferenceData", "");
```

This is how I set the data to my RecyclerView:

```java
// Set plan data
Plans plan = new Plans("123", "E3rft Split", "11.10.2016");
// Add Object to list
planList.add(plan);

// Notify data changes
pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My `Plans` class:

```java
public class Plans {
    private String planTitle, planType, planDate;

    public Plans(String planTitle, String planType, String planDate) {
        this.planTitle = planTitle;
        this.planType = planType;
        this.planDate = planDate;
    }

    public void setPlanTitle(String planTitle) {
        this.planTitle = planTitle;
    }

    public String getPlanTitle() {
        return planTitle;
    }

    public void setPlanType(String planType) {
        this.planType = planType;
    }

    public String getPlanType() {
        return planType;
    }

    public void setPlanDate(String planDate) {
        this.planDate = planDate;
    }

    public String getPlanDate() {
        return planDate;
    }
}
```

My `onCreateView`:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);

    preparePlansData();

    return view;
}
```

My `preparePlansData()`:

```java
private void preparePlansData() {

    // Set plan data
    Plans plan = new Plans("123", "fkfjfjeje", "21.04.1977");
    // Add Object to list
    planList.add(plan);

    plan = new Plans("test", "tttt", "22.01.2017");
    planList.add(plan);

    // Notify data changes
    pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

My question is how can I get the information out of the string array into my adapter? I also need to format the date before adding. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This tutorial should help you out https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Not realy helping for the first view. I need to get the data out of my array and create the entries for my RecyclerView.

Comment: No answer? I need this...

Comment: Parse this json with `Gson` to some model objects and use them in adapter.

Comment: @RadekJ I'm a beginner on this. Please can you show me how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about **Gson** here:

http://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library

After that you will be able to write code like that:

```
 Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Plans>>(){}.getType();
 Map<Integer, Plans> myMap = gson.fromJson("your json from db", type);
```

and use this map.values() in your adapter

your `Plans` class should look like this:

```
class Plans {
    String order_number;
    String typ_first;
    String typ_last;
    String order_date_time;
}
```

If you want another field names you have to use `@SerializedName` annotation

Finally, you should write something like that, (I do not know if syntax is 100% do not have IDE open now) :

```
private void preparePlansData() {
    String plansData = plansPreferenceData.getString("plansPreferenceData", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Plans>>(){}.getType();
    Map<Integer, Plans> myMap = gson.fromJson(plansData, type); 
    planList.addAll(myMap.values());

    // Notify data changes
    pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and modify your model class:

```
public class Plans {
    @SerializedName("order_number")
    String planTitle;
    @SerializedName("typ_last") 
    String planType; 
    @SerializedName("order_date_time")  
    String planDate;
    ....
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: But how to extract the different informations? In this array are two objects so there should be two different lines

Comment: use `Map` here is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15943171/2318843

Comment: Looking good. Can you give me an example for one value from my string? Don't forget that the result amount is not static like in the solution you've posted

Comment: This looks so difficult :'( I've a method in my fragment where I set the data and not in the adapter and I'm calling the method in my onCreateView method

Comment: updated answer, dont forget to add Gson library to your gradle file

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "success"

Comment: I've removed the success string after don't need it anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code (you can remove @Test annotation):

```
class Plans {
    String typ_firstString;
    String typ_last;
    String order_date_time;

    public Plans(String typ_firstString, String typ_last, String order_date_time) {
        this.typ_firstString = typ_firstString;
        this.typ_last = typ_last;
        this.order_date_time = order_date_time;
    }
}

class PlansResponse {
    boolean status;
    List<Plans> plans;
}

@Test
public void testPlacesResponseDeserializer() { 
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(PlansResponse.class, new PlansResponseDeserializer())
            .create();
    String jsonString = "{\"success\":true,\"0\":{\"order_number\":\"078\",\"typ_first\":\"E3rft\",\"typ_last\":\"Split\",\"order_date_time\":\"2016-10-11 19:20:03\"},\"1\":{\"order_number\":\"166\",\"typ_first\":\"E483f\",\"typ_last\":\"Split_test\",\"order_date_time\":\"2016-10-12 18:39:30\"}}";
    PlansResponse plansResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, PlansResponse.class);

    assert plansResponse.status == true;
    assert plansResponse.plans.size() == 2;
}

class PlansResponseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<PlansResponse> {

    private String getElementAsString(JsonObject jsonObject, String key) {
        JsonElement element = jsonObject.get(key);
        return element.getAsString();
    }

    @Override
    public PlansResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        PlansResponse plansResponse = new PlansResponse();

        List<Plans> plansList = new ArrayList<>();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, JsonObject>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, JsonElement> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();

            if("success".equals(key)) {
                JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = (JsonPrimitive) entry.getValue();
                plansResponse.status = jsonPrimitive.getAsBoolean();
                continue;
            }

            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)entry.getValue();
            String typ_firstString = getElementAsString(jsonObject, "typ_first");
            String typ_last = getElementAsString(jsonObject, "typ_last");
            String order_date_time = getElementAsString(jsonObject, "order_date_time");
            plansList.add(new Plans(typ_firstString, typ_last, order_date_time));
        }
        plansResponse.plans = plansList;
        return plansResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I format a date like this `2016-10-11 19:20:03` to this `11.10.2016`

Comment: read about `SimpleDateFormat`: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Comment: And I can do this with my json string too?

Comment: not whole json string but only with `order_date_time` when it is set

Comment: Ah okay understand. I'll try it

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = formatDate.parse(plan.getPlanDate()); But I'm getting an error: Unparseable date: "2016-10-11 19:20:03"

Comment: becouse first you need to obtain date object from ` "2016-10-11 19:20:03"` so here the pattern is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, after you parse String to Date you should use another SimpleDataFormat object to format Date back to String

Comment: Now I got! Thanks a lot for your help!