# How to parse JSON with Gson, when there is no @SerializedName

Tags: json, serialization, gson

I have the following JSON document:

```
{
  "1786042": {},
  "2064178": {
    "initialImportDate": "2015-11-13T12:22:53.585",
    "hideCrossedOutPrice": false,
    "salesCount": 0,
  },
  ...
}
```

How can I get access to the list of products, which are defined by id and not a name, that could be deserialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert JSON to a HashMap using Gson?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TypeToken` here:

I am assuming a class named `Product`, which contains properties like `initialImportDate`, `hideCrossedOutPrice` etc.

Now You can use `TypeToken` to deserialize this json, like this:

```
Type productMap = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Product> >() {}.getType();
Map<Integer, Product> result= gson.fromJson(jsonString, productMap);
```

Comment: I did not mention, that I am using Retrofit as well. So I have a Call  like `call.enqueue(new Callback<TypeToken<Map<Integer, AwesomeProduct>>>()` and this delivers me `Failed to invoke protected com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken() with no args`

Comment: @4ndro1d Sachin Gupta has provided you a generic solution that is used with "vanilla" Gson when it's the only way to "write down" the actual type information. You callback must accept `Map<Integer, AwesomeProduct>` and not type token, because Retrofit should be able to analyze the interface method return type itself.