# Insert Record to MySQL in Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, json

I'm working with adding of records to MySQL in Android Studio. In my api, when I successfully insert records, it gives me this `JSON` result.

**{"status":"success"}**

How can I integrate and code this to my Android, that whenever I insert correct values will only check the status. What I know is the old way i.e. the use of `HTTPClient` and `HTTP Post` which is not available in newer versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use any of the network libraries like Volley or retrofit and call the url with post or get method respectively and you will recieve the data/ status back in the json. Now convet that Json to the Hashmap and check the status and update the UI correspondingly.

Refer the following links

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

[How can I convert JSON to a HashMap using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson)