# Converting arbitrary JSON from POST body to a map JAVA REST

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jackson

I am currently working with a **REST** web service. one of the methods is a POST request, in which the user sends some configuration details in the format of **JSON**. The number of configuration parameters and the parameters themselves will vary. Basically, it would look something like :

```
{

"configParam1" : "value1", 
"configParam2" : "value2",
"configParam3" : "value3"
}
```

or it could look like this:

```
{  
"configParam1 ": "value1",

"configParam2" : "value2"

}
```

meaning that the number of keys and the actual keys themselves would vary.
I need to convert this **JSON** to a map.

I know that you can do so by creating a **POJO** and it will be converted according to the class, however, given that the parameters vary, I can't have a hard class definition to convert to.

Is there any way to go around this?

Generally, Instead of putting something like :

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATIONJSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATIONJSON)
methodName(MyClassObject postJSONresponse){ 
}
```

can I just do:

```
@POST  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATIONJSON) .  
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATIONJSON) .  
methodName(Map (string,string) postJSONrepsonse){

} ?
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Please Help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I used GSON.

Here is the link that I found an answer on:

[How can I convert JSON to a HashMap using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson)

My funciton looks something like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATIONJSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATIONJSON)
methodName(String json){ 
// convert the string to a Map using GSON:

Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = 
gson.fromJson({'k1':'apple','k2':'orange'}", type);

//now myMap is a map (of type : linkedTreeMap, which implements map
}
```

you have to import Gson Type Token and Type I believe.

Hope this helps anyone who needs it :)