# Java extract information from JSON

Tags: java, json, jenkins

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
  "actions": [
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
      "causes": [
        {
          "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause",
          "shortDescription": "Started by user SYSTEM",
          "userId": "SYSTEM",
          "userName": "SYSTEM"
        },
        {
          "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause",
          "shortDescription": "Started by user SYSTEM",
          "userId": "SYSTEM",
          "userName": "SYSTEM"
        },
        {
          "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause",
          "shortDescription": "Started by user SYSTEM",
          "userId": "SYSTEM",
          "userName": "SYSTEM"
        },
        {
          "_class": "com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildCause",
          "shortDescription": "Rebuilds build #1",
          "upstreamBuild": 1,
          "upstreamProject": "gcimpoies-test5",
          "upstreamUrl": "job/gcimpoies-test5/"
        },
        {
          "_class": "com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildCause",
          "shortDescription": "Rebuilds build #1",
          "upstreamBuild": 1,
          "upstreamProject": "gcimpoies-test5",
          "upstreamUrl": "job/gcimpoies-test5/"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
      "causes": [
        {
          "_class": "com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildCause",
          "shortDescription": "Rebuilds build #1",
          "upstreamBuild": 1,
          "upstreamProject": "gcimpoies-test5",
          "upstreamUrl": "job/gcimpoies-test5/"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {
      "_class": "com.sonyericsson.jenkins.plugins.bfa.model.FailureCauseBuildAction"
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
  ],
  "artifacts": [

  ],
  "building": false,
  "description": null,
  "displayName": "#2",
  "duration": 15,
  "estimatedDuration": 61,
  "executor": null,
  "fullDisplayName": "gcimpoies-test5 #2",
  "id": "2",
  "keepLog": false,
  "number": 2,
  "queueId": 6,
  "result": "FAILURE",
  "timestamp": 1522153325922,
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/gcimpoies-test5/2/",
  "builtOn": "",
  "changeSet": {
    "_class": "hudson.scm.EmptyChangeLogSet",
    "items": [

    ],
    "kind": null
  },
  "culprits": [

  ]
}
```

And I want to extract the username: **SYSTEM**

I tried using JsonSlurper but with no luck. I believe the right way to go is using JSONObject instead.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to access this variable in `Groovy script` right?

Comment: No, java code instead.

Comment: Accessing this in a groovy script would be a lot easier

Comment: you definetly can extract needed variable/value in groovy JsonSlupper, can you please share code how you tried it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing json in `java`. Here I am pasting the code to convert json into Map. So that you can simply access json as map object.

```
Map map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

For more info, please read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39444157/5003256).

Comment: Are you sure you can use that kind of dependencies inside Jenkins Pipeline file ? Honestly I havebig doubths there

Comment: I don't think he mentioned as `pipeline scripting`. Instead he is writing `java` code. That's y I told him this solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map buildDetailsMap;
    buildDetailsMap = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
    if (buildDetailsMap != null) {
        List actions = (List) buildDetailsMap.get("actions");
        Map actionZero = (Map) actions.get(0);
        List causes = (List) actionZero.get("causes");
        Map causeZero = (Map) causes.get(0);
        username = (String) causeZero.get("userName");
    }
```

This is how I did it. Thanks SV Madhava Revy