# Parsing JSON object into a Map using Gson - JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I have a map property:

```
private Map<String, Attribute> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

`Attribute` object looks like this:

```
public class Attribute{
     private String value;
     private String name;

//with constructor setters and getters
}
```

How do I represent attributes `Map` object as JSON?

I am getting a `JsonSyntaxException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

when I'm trying to convert JSON object using `fromJson()` in the following code:

```
Attribute attribute = Gson().fromJson(jsonObect,Attribute.class)
```

My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
   "attributes":[
      {
         "name":"some name",
         "value":"some value"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easy to check:

```
    Map<String,Attribute> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("key_0", new Attribute("value_0", "name_0"));// I added constructor and getter/setter methods to class Attribute
    attributes.put("key_1", new Attribute("value_1", "name_1"));
    attributes.put("key_2", new Attribute("value_2", "name_2"));
    //serialize using ObjectMapper
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var s = mapper.writeValueAsString(attributes);
    System.out.println(s);
```

output:

```
{
   "key_2":{
      "value":"value_2",
      "name":"name_2"
   },
   "key_1":{
      "value":"value_1",
      "name":"name_1"
   },
   "key_0":{
      "value":"value_0",
      "name":"name_0"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting: `"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"` error when I'm trying to convert JSON object using `fromJson()` in the following code:
>
> `Attribute attribute = Gson().fromJson(jsonObect,Attribute.class)`

The following *JSON object* doesn't match either a single `Attribute` object or a map `Map<String, Attribute>`:

```
{
   "attributes":[
      {
         "name":"some name",
         "value":"some value"
      }
   ]
}
```

Have a look carefully, the value mapped to the key `"attributes"` is a *JSON-array*.

Hence, you can parse it successfully into a map of type `Map<String, List<Attribute>>`

That's how it can be implemented using `Gson.fromJson()` and `TypeToken` (*for more options, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson)*):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String jsonStr = """
        {
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "name":"some name",
                  "value":"some value"
               }
            ]
         }""";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    Type mapStrByStr = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Attribute>>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, List<Attribute>> map = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, mapStrByStr);

    System.out.println(map);
    }
}


public static class Attribute{
    private String value;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Attribute{" +
            "value='" + value + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
{attributes=[Attribute{value='some value', name='some name'}]}
```